# Proper (tree) display of Qt project using .pro and .pri in QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is it possible to display more then only one extra level using project include files (.pri).
For example if `.pro` file includes `.pri` file which includes two `.pri` files.

- .pro

  - .pri

    - .pri
    - .pri

In QtCreator (Projects) display is misleading:

- .pro

  - .pri
  - .pri
  - .pri

It simply doesn't respect where the `.pri` file is in the file system and displays them as a  at the same `.pro` level. Or am I doing something wrong or just expecting to much? I am using `Qt 4.7.4` and `QtCreator 2.2.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is some kind of workaround if you ignore the second level of .pri files and just use a new directory and move all includes to root .pri file. For example:

- .pro

  - .pri

    - new dir A (instead of another .pri)
    - new dir B (instead of another .pri)

QtCreator (Projects) display:

- .pro

  - .pri

    - Headers

      - new dir A
      - new dir B
    - Sources

      - new dir A
      - new dir B

Good thing about it is that you get to keep the same file structure. I am still hoping they implement detection of new level(s) of .pri. But please let me know if you find out something more that I heaven't.

Comment: Marking as correct even if it's work around, if you find a better solution please let us know.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Qt Creator 3.6 nested `.pri` files are shown in a tree. You can check [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-487) which is resolved.